# Absolutely postioned div moving with margin top of another static postioned div

Tags: html, css, position

I have a body containing two div's one is an absolutely positioned div and another one is a static default positioned div, i want the absolutely positioned div to take the full height of the screen which it takes but the problem that next arises is when i try to apply margin top to the statically positioned div, it also gets added to the absolutely positioned div.

How can I make the absolutely positioned div not get the margin of the sibling div ?

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}

.div-1 {
  position: absolute;
  border: 2px solid red;
  width: 90%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 100vh;
}

.div-2 {
  height: 200px;
  width: 90%;
  background-color: blueviolet;
  margin-top: 8rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="div-1"></div>
<div class="div-2"></div>
```

Comment: I have no clue, but removing the `position: relative;` from the body fixed the issue

Comment: does not seem to work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you have [margin collapse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing) on the body element.  Margin collapse happens when there's no content separating parent and descendants elements (such as the body and `.div-2`).  You can easily fix this by setting the `display` property of the `body` element to `flow-root`.

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  /* Set flow-root */
  display: flow-root;
}

.div-1 {
  position: absolute;
  border: 2px solid red;
  width: 90%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 100vh;
}

.div-2 {
  height: 200px;
  width: 90%;
  background-color: blueviolet;
  margin-top: 8rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="div-1"></div>
<div class="div-2"></div>
```

Comment: thanks for explaining where i was wrong, and your solution worked!

Answer (score 0):

```
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}

.div-1 {
  position: absolute;
  border: 2px solid red;
  width: 90%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 100vh;
  z-index:1;
  
}

.div-2 {
  height: 200px;
  width: 90%;
  background-color: blueviolet;
  top: 8rem;
  position: inherit;
  
}
```

Use top and position inherit instead of margin-top, check if it can be use.